# Realizar acción cuando el usuario deniega para siempre los permisos de ubicación en Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente código que se encarga de mostrar un toast si el usuario deniega los permisos de ubicación una vez son solicitados, he creado una clase que se encarga de verificar si el usuario ha aceptado los permisos o no:

```
class PermisionRequester(
    activity: ComponentActivity,
    private val permission: String ,
    private val onRationale: () -> Unit = {},
    private val onDenied: () -> Unit = {})
{
    private var onGranted: () -> Unit = {}
    private val permissionLauncher =
        activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
            when {
                isGranted -> onGranted()
                activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission) ->
                    onRationale()
                else -> onDenied
            }
        }

    fun runWithPermission(body: () -> Unit) {
        onGranted = body
        permissionLauncher.launch(permission)
    }
```

Y en función de la acción que haya realizado debería mostrar los siguientes toast:

```
val coarsePermision = PermisionRequester (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    onRationale = { Toast.makeText(this, "Debes activar la ubicación para poder hacer búsquedas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()},
    onDenied =  {Toast.makeText(this, "Si quieres usar esta función deberás activar la ubicación manualmente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()})
```

Si el usuario los deniega una vez sí muestra el toast del apartado "onRationale" pero si los deniega para siempre no hace ninguna acción, cuando debería de mostrar el toast del apartado "onDenied". ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que preguntas:

> Si el usuario los deniega una vez sí muestra el toast del apartado
> "onRationale" pero **si los deniega para siempre no hace ninguna
> acción**, cuando debería de mostrar el toast del apartado "onDenied".
> ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**Si el usuario deniega para siempre los permisos, no puedes forzar programaticamente a que le vuelva a mostrar el permiso**, la única opción para este caso es mostrar un mensaje al usuario y abrir la configuración de la aplicación para que el usuario mismo acepte los permisos:

```
val intent = Intent(
    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
    Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Puedes ver un ejemplo completo en la [respuesta de Nabin Bhandari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288306/250260)

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por tu respuesta. No quiero que vuelva a mostrar la ventana para activar el permiso. Lo que desearía que hiciera es que muestre el toast indicado: onDenied =  {Toast.makeText(this, "Si quieres usar esta función deberás activar la ubicación manualmente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}) pero no entiendo por qué motivo no llega a hacerlo. Podrías ayudarme? Gracias.